# How to access DynamoDB tables without exposing API credentials

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-cloudformation

We use CloudFormation to deploy our platform. Is here a way to allow the application instance access to the DynamoDB tables without exposing API credentials?
I read about creating an IAM role that has the right permission and use instance profile. How do I achieve this? can someone please provide more details and explain what instance profile is?

Answer (score 1):

As per AWS IAM documentation, Instance Profile is:

> An instance profile is a container for an IAM role that you can use to pass role information to an EC2 instance when the instance starts.

So, this is a feature provided by AWS so that IAM credentials don't have to be stored in EC2 instances to execute AWS APIs. Also, this feature aids in granting only the permission specified in the desired IAM role to the EC2 instance. Also, you can use the same Instance profile on multiple instances. This way, you don't have to update credentials on each EC2 instance whenever you change the credentials. So, while launching the EC2 instance, you can specify the instance profile. The instance profile is attached to an IAM role. The EC2 instance will get the IAM role and all the IAM credentials. You just need to set the AWS region before using the APIs.

**How to do it**:
 
1) Create an IAM role using: [create-role](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/create-role.html)
2) Create Instance Profile using: [create-instance-profile](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/create-instance-profile.html). The output of this step will contain the Arn for the Instance Profile. This needs to be used in step 4.
3) Add role to Instance Profile using: [add-role-to-instance-profile](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/add-role-to-instance-profile.html)
4) Launch instance using [run-instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html). Specify the --iam-instance-profile option as below:

```
--iam-instance-profile Arn=instanceArn
```

The instanceArn is got from step 2.

The same can be achieved using AWS Console. The Screenshot below shows, how you can specify the role during launch of an EC2 instance:

[image: EC2 Instance Launch using AWS Console, specifying IAM role]

For more details please see [Using Instance Profiles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html) and section 'Permissions Required for Using Roles with Amazon EC2' at page 190 of [AWS IAM User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/iam-ug.pdf).